# Adding Views at run time in android issue

Tags: android, android-view

Iam adding vies at runtime programatically successfully..
But iam facing a problem...
Actually I can add views at runtime and drag them to a new position on the screen..
When I add a new view all previously added views come back to a default position.. (set in LayoutParams).. What's the reason???

below is the code of adding views at runtime

```
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
Bitmap bm  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.item4);
ImageView Image = new ImageView(MMSDesignActivity.this);
Image.setImageBitmap(bm);
myRelativelayout.addView(Image, params);
```

Kindly tell me a solutiom for this...
Thanks inadvance...

Comment: probably a matter of animation fillAfter ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace LayoutParams initialization code by this code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: I have used same code above..
    **params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);**
This line adds view in center of layout other wise default location is top left corner of layout...

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout as a parent view.